# Generate apk from Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, apk

Does anyone know any way to generate the .apk file, from Visual Studio Code? Or if it can? Should I sign the application?

The code is based on `ionic frame` with`Angular 4.4`.

I have seen many tutorials but they all use the compiler `Microsoft Visual Studio`. I am using `Visual Studio Code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

highly recommend to read and follow these two articles:

1. how to setup your machine for Android

https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/android

2. how to build app and sign and submit to Google Play:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/publishing/play-store

you do not need specifically VS code’s terminal to run build commands. You just need  a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

In **vscode** use the built in **terminal** for making .apk with this command :

*Debug*

```
 ionic cordova build android
```

*Release*

```
  ionic cordova build android --release
```

and use **jarsigner** to sign the  app

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generate an apk file with VS Code.

Click on Terminal menu then click on New terminal, it is open terminal in vs code in terminal write this command:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

This commend is using to generate a production app.

```
ionic cordova build android
```

This commend is using to generate a debug app.